# Checking if input file value is bigger than 10^9

Tags: c++

So basically, I have something like this -
Input file with 2 integers.
Code, something like this -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  unsigned long long n, k;
  ifstream input_file("file.txt");
  input_file >> n >> k;
  if(n >= 10^9 || k >= 10^9) {
    cout << "0" << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

So, is there any chance to check if any of theese two integers are bigger than 10^9? Basically, if I assign thoose integers to unsigned long long, and if they are bigger than 10^9, they automatically turn to some random value, that fits inside unsigned long long, am I right, and that means that there is no chance to check it, or am I'm missing something?

Comment: Just a little warning: `10^9` in C++ is the xor operation between 10 and 9. To obtain what you want you should either use a `double` literal like `1e9`, or write 1000000000 explicitly, remembering the appropriate type suffix (e.g. `ul`) if on your platform `int` isn't big enough for it.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Integer literals always have a type that's big enough, provided such a type exists. The suffix is just a *minimum*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On most platforms, an `unsigned long long` will be able to store 10<sup>9</sup> with no problem.  You just need to say:

`if (n >= 1000000000ull)`

If an `unsigned long long` is 64-bits, for example, which is common, you can store up to 2<sup>64</sup>

Answer (score 3):

I'm bad at counting zeroes. That's the machine's job. What about `1e9` instead of a bit operation `10^9`.

Comment: So basically, if I write if(k >= 1e9) { cout << "0"; } that will work?

Comment: There is some room for numbers after `1e9` with long long numbers. This should work. For very large integers one has to implement a simple string comparison in style what @user1071136 suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Read into a string:

```
std::string s;
input_file >> s;
```

and check if it's longer than 9 characters. If it's exactly 9, see that it's not exactly `"1000000000"` (1 and eight 0's).

Answer (score 0):

For 10^9 you need to write `1000000000LL`. In C++ `^` is the bitwise XOR operator, not exponentiaion. You also need the `LL` to ensure that the literal constant is interpreted as `long long` rather than just `int`.

```
if (n >= 1000000000LL || k >= 1000000000LL)
{
    ...
}
```

Of course if the user enters a value which is too large to be represented by a `long long` (greater than 2^63-1, typically) then you have a bigger problem.